# MariaDB Columnstore 1.4 on MariaDB Community Server 10.5 Alpha

Tags: mariadb, columnstore

Per MariaDB's website, in the Columnstore section (https://mariadb.com/downloads/#mariadb_platform-mariadb_columnstore):

> MariaDB ColumnStore 1.4 is now part of MariaDB Enterprise Server 10.4,
>   and **will be part of the next MariaDB Community Server 10.5 alpha
>   release.**

However, the .tar for the MariaDB Community Server 10.5 alpha (recently released) does not contain any .deb files containing the text "columnstore" (I would expect to see something along the lines of "MariaDB-columnstore-platform" and "MariaDB-columnstore-engine" based on the only documentation I can find for Columnstore 1.4, which is written not for the community version but for Enterprise: https://mariadb.com/docs/deploy/col14/). I cannot find any equivalent documentation pertaining to Columnstore 1.4 in MariaDB Community 10.5 alpha, even though MariaDB's website states that Columnstore 1.4 was released in that version, and several articles published on other websites reference it as being included in the release as well.

Has anyone used Columnstore 1.4 on MariaDB Community 10.5 alpha? Maybe Columnsotre's inclusion in 10.5 alpha was simply cancelled and references of its inclusion were never deleted throughout the website? If someone has gotten it working, can you outline how?

Thanks

Comment: If you have installed 10.5, do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'has%';`

Comment: @RickJames No result. What variable(s) are you thinking might be returned? There are no variables in MariaDB docs which begin with "has" (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/)

Comment: Oops, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have%';` -- looking for something like `have_columnstore`.

Comment: There is no `have_columnstore` variable, or any variable containing the text "columnstore"

Comment: So, it sounds like ColumnStore is either unavailable or needs to somehow be added.

Comment: @RickJames Right. The enterprise edition says to add it thru commands which reference packages `mariadb-columnstore-platform` and `mariadb-plugin-columnstore`. These packages do not appear to exist in the community edition, version 10.5. This is despite the MariaDB website stating "MariaDB ColumnStore 1.4 is now part of MariaDB Enterprise Server 10.4, and will be part of the next MariaDB Community Server 10.5 alpha release." Perhaps they decided to leave it out at the last minute. Would just be nice to have some confirmation or clarification as to the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

But 10.5 is not "released" yet.  The release cycle is to put out 10.x.0, which likely to be riddled with issues.  Then 10.x.1, which cleans up some of the worst problems.  Etc.  Eventually, 10.x.y is issued as a "Release candidate".  The hardy "early adopters" should be trying this out, but not putting it in production.  Finally, about 10.x.10, they will issue a "GA" (Generally available) version.  This has all the features for 10.x included and all show-stopper bugs dealt with.

Note that the page for 10.5 is calling 10.5.1 "beta"; it is not yet RC or GA.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-is-mariadb-105/

It is not uncommon for a feature to not make it into the ".0" version.  But it is likely to be in before the RC release.  I *guess* that they tried to put Columnstore into .0, but something really bad happened, so they backed it out.

Perhaps someone in MariaDB will spot this Q&A and give you a better answer.

Patience.

Comment: A bug can be filed at jira.mariadb.org .